# Visual Studio Code; how to open two Python shells side-by-side

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can open a terminal with command "Python: Create Terminal" and that works great. It is using my selected Python Interpreter that I created with `pipenv`. But I want to create two of these terminals side-by-side.

If I split the terminal, a new bash terminal starts that only knows about the system installed Python.

If I create another Python terminal, it opens by itself. The two terminals are running but I can only display one or the other

Is there a way to have two Python terminals open and displayed at the same time?
I'm on windows10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the `Create Terminal` command, no. But you can copy and paste the shell command that gets executed by `Create Terminal` in the second shell and it will lead to the same result.

We also have an open [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1387) that would solve this by automatically executing the appropriate command on every opened terminal. Feel free to leave a :+1: reaction to the issue to let us know you would like to see the feature implemented.

Comment: interesting ticket. I'll think about the problem some more before adding anything there. It's not an easy problem when you're dealing in multiple languages! thanks. oh, yeah, and `pipenv` shell in that second shell errors out with a traceback. I can still give the full path the python binary and everything is fine.